# Why isn't this simple Javascript concatenation working?

Tags: javascript, css

I tried all of the following, but none of them work:

```
iframe.style[transform] = 'scale('+(scale)+', 1) translate(-'+(0-scale)+'%, 0)';

iframe.style[transform] = 'scale('+(scale)+', 1) translate(-'+(-scale)+'%, 0)';

var translate = 0-scale;
iframe.style[transform] = 'scale('+(scale)+', 1) translate(-'+translate+'%, 0)';

var translate = 0-scale;
iframe.style[transform] = 'scale('+(scale)+', 1) translate(-'+translate.toString+'%, 0)';
```

However, it does work if I do this:

```
iframe.style[transform] = 'scale('+(scale)+', 1) translate(-0%, 0)';
```

Why shouldn't it work? I'm using Firefox 7 on Windows 7

Comment: Both `0-scale` and `-scale` will probably be negative. In that case, you'll end up with two minus signs in the resulting argument to `translate()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that it may generate invalid syntax. Here:

```
'translate(-'+(0-scale)+'%, 0)';
           ^      ^
           |      |____ possible negative number
           |
           |___________ literal minus sign
```

may generate the following string:

```
translate(--0%, 0);
           ^
           |___________ double minus, which is invalid CSS
```

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't matter, but have you tried:

```
iframe.style[transform] = "scale(" + scale.toString() + ", 1); translate(-" + translate.toString() + "%, 0);";
```